# Character and String manipulation in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Okay so as a part of an assignment I need to continuously read characters from the user and store them in memory first . Then I need to retrieve them from memory and process them (filter out some unwanted characters) and then print them to the console . My current implementation is using load byte and store byte (lb and sb commands) but the assignment requires me to implement it with store word and load word (i.e. pack the bytes first then store them as a word when reading and when processing the string load words from memory and then process them byte by byte ).I know that mips is 32-bit and that a word is 4 bytes and all that but I am really stuck and can't think of anything thus the need to post.Sorry if there is an obvious solution or if my post lacks details. I will post my code below

```
.data 
 ## Data declaration section

 ## The data declaration section is the same as that of the previous lab exercise 
 ## Two sets of 100 consecutive bytes are allocated and then the strings to be printed
 ## are declared 
    
 ## String to be printed
    out_string: .asciiz "\nPlease Enter your Character: \n"
    out_string1: .asciiz "\nThe string is:\n"

    buffer: .space 100   ## Allocate 100 consecutive bytes in memory
                         ## One character takes up 1 byte ,thus for 100 characters 
                         ## as per the assignment's needs, we need 100 bytes , this buffer
                         ## is for the reading of the user's input
                         ## This buffer is used for reading the user's input only

    buffer1: .space 100  ## Allocate another 100 consecutive bytes in memory
                         ## This buffer is used for filtering out the unwanted symbols
                         ## And contains the final string to be printed 


.text 
main:           ## Code execution starts here - MIPS - Assembly language instructions go 
                ## in text segment .  As per instructions 'main' does 4 jal(jump and links)
                ## code commands and executes exit 

    jal init                ## call the init() routine to initialize some parameters

    add $a0 , $s4 , $zero   ## pass the address of buffer(=string1 in assignment) into $a0
                            ## as an argument for the process_string routine 
                            ## (base address of buffer is in $s4)

    jal get_string          ## call the get_string(int string1, int num_characters) routine 
                            ## to read input from the user

    add $a1 , $s5 , $zero   ## pass the address of buffer1(=string2 in assignment) into $a1
                            ## as an argument for the process_string routine 
                            ## (base address of buffer1 is in $s5)

    add $a2 , $v0 , $zero   ## after the execution of get_string $v0 contains the number of 
                            ## characters that were read from the user. We store the current 
                            ## value of $v0 into register $a2 because the number of characters
                            ## that were read from the user is passed as an argument into 
                            ## the process_string routine 

    jal process_string      ## call the process_string(int string1,int string2,int num_characters) 
                            ## routine to apply some filtering to the characters provided by the user
    
    add $a0 , $a1 , $v0   ## a0 is a memory address : the base address of buffer1(=string2) + 
                          ## the number of characters that exist in the post-processing  string 

    jal output_string       ## call the output_string(int string2) routine to print the processed string
    
    li $v0, 10              ## terminate the program
    syscall 

init:  

############ In this routine we populate the $s0,$s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5,$s6 registers that 
############ are preserved across calls of routines .

    li $s0 , 32             ## 32 = SP in ASCII 
    li $s1 , 57             ## 57 = 9  in ASCII 
    li $s2 , 64             ## 64 = @  in ASCII 
    li $s3 , 90             ## 90 = Z  in ASCII  
    la $s4 , buffer         ## load the base address of buffer(string1)  
    la $s5 , buffer1        ## load the base address of buffer1(string2) 
    li $s6 , 100            ## 100 times is the maximum amount of times the reading loop can run
    
    jr $ra                  ## continue execution back in main 


get_string:

############ In this routine we print the string : "Please enter your character" and proceed
############ to read input from the user for up to 100 characters. If the user enters @ we
############ stop reading and revert back to main where the processing of the input kicks off

    add $t9 , $a0 , $zero   ## First save the argument passed into the routine to a temporary
                            ## register $t9 in order to preserve it across syscalls  . 
                            ## The argument is the starting address of the 
                            ## reading buffer so now $t0 contains the base address of buffer
                            ## (the buffer used for reading = string1 in the assignment) 
                            ## $t9 is used to restore the value of $a0 later .

    add $t0 , $t9 , $zero   ## Copy the content of $t9 to $t0 to use it later in the loop0 

    li   $t1 , 0            ## Initialize a counter for the loop that follows

loop0: ## The loop that prints the "Please enter your character" message and 
       ## gets input from the user
       ## We can safely overwrite $a0 register since we have transferred its value to 
       ## $t0 .
    
       ##print the message: "Please Enter your Character"
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, out_string
       syscall


       ## read a character from the user 
       li $v0, 12
       syscall

       add $t2 , $v0 , $zero        ## Move the user's input to $t2 

       beq $s2 , $t2 , exitloop0    ## Check if the character entered is @ (@ = 64 is in $s2)
       
       beq $t1 , $s6 , exitloop0    ## Check if the routine has already been called 100 times

       sb $t2 , 0($t0)              ## Store the input in memory

       addi $t1 , $t1 , 1           ## Increment the counter of the loop 

       addi $t0 , $t0 , 1           ## Go to the next memory position of the reading buffer 

       j loop0 

exitloop0:

############ If execution gets here it means that either the user entered @
############ or the program has already read 100 characters from the user
############ Either case it is time to return back to main . The return value of
############ this routine is the number of characters read from the user . 
############ So we pass to $v0 the counter of the loop($t1). The character @ is not counted.
############ We also restore $a0 as well using $t9

       add $a0 , $t9 , $zero        ## Restore $a0 

       add $v0 , $t1 , $zero        ## Pass the return value

       jr $ra                       ## Continue execution back in main 


process_string:


        add $t0 , $a0 , $zero       ## t-registers are not preserved across calls in mips and 
                                    ## thus can be overwritten
        add $t1 , $a2 , $zero       ## $t0 contains the base address of the reading buffer
                                    ## and $t1 the number of characters read from the user
        add $t2 , $t1 , $t0         ## since we have allocated 100 consecutive bytes in the 
                                    ## declaration section the last character is located 
                                    ## at : $t0+$t1 . We perform this operation and store the 
                                    ## result in $t2 . And now $t2 contains the memory address
                                    ## in which the last symbol that was read from the user 
                                    ## resides.

        li $t6 , 0                  ## This is a counter that shows how many characters there 
                                    ## are in the new string (after processing)

        add $t5 , $a1 , $zero       ## $t5 contains the base address of the buffer used for
                                    ## used for processing

        
loop1: 

        beq $t0 , $t2 , exitloop1   ## The main termination condition for this loop is 
                                    ## for $t0 to reach the memory address of the last symbbol
                                    ## that was read from the user.

        lb  $t3 , 0($t0)            ## Load a character , from the memory position indicated by
                                    ## the current value of $t0 ,into register $t3

    ## We want to exclude non-alphanumeric characters ## 

    ## The non alphanumeric characters have ASCII codes between :
    ## a) 32 = SP,space (not included) and 48 = 0 (not included)
    ## b) 57 = 9 (not included) and 65 = A (not included) 
    ## c) 90 = Z (not included) and 97 = a (not included)
    ## d) any ASCII code above 122 = z 
    
    

    ## Case a

    slti $t4 , $t3 , 48 ## $t4 = 1 if $t3 < 48 else 0

    slt $t8 , $s0 , $t3 ## $t8 = 1 if $s0 < $t3 (32<$t3) else 0

    and $t4 , $t4 , $t8  ## we want to find the numbers between 32 and 48 so both $t8 and
                             ## $t1 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                             ## in this region

    beq $t4 , 1 , nonalphanumeric   ## now if $t4 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                        ## a non alphanumeric




    ## Case b 

    slti $t4, $t3 , 64 ## $t4 = 1 if $t3 < 64 else 0  
 
    slt $t8 , $s1 , $t3 ## $t8 = 1 if $s1 < $t3 (57<$t3) else 0

    and $t4 , $t4 , $t8 ## we want to find the numbers between 57 and 65 so both $t1 and
                        ## $t8 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                        ## in this region 

    beq $t4 , 1 , nonalphanumeric ## now if $t1 does indeed equal 1 we have a non alphanumeric
    



    ## Case c

    slti $t4 , $t3 , 97 ## $t1 = 1 if $t3 < 97 else 0 

    slt $t8 , $s3 , $t3 ## $t8 = 1 if $s3 < $t3 (90<$t3) else 0 

    and $t4 , $t4 , $t8 ## we want to find the numbers between 90 and 97 so both $t1 and
                        ## $t8 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                        ## in this region 
    beq $t4 , 1 , nonalphanumeric ## now if $t1 does indeed equal 1 we have a non alphanumeric
    



    ## Case d 

    slti $t8 , $t3 , 122 ## $t8 = 1 if $t3 < 122 else 0 
    beq  $t8, $zero , nonalphanumeric

    ## By this stage all possibilities that $t3 contains a non-alphanumeric
    ## character are eliminated . If $t3 contained a non alphanumeric character execution 
    ## continues at label non alphanumeric 


    sb $t3 , 0($t5)   ## store the character (which by now is cretainly not a non alphanumeric)
                      ## to memory address indicated by the current value of $t1
                      ## $t1 was initialized to contain the base address of buffer1(=string2)
    
    addi $t5 , $t5 , 1  ## Increment t1 so that next time the loop is executed t1 points to the
                        ## directly next memory address.

    addi $t0 , $t0 , 1 ## We also increment $t0 since our main condition to exit the loop
                       ## is to read all the characters from memory addresses
                       ## inidicated by the reading buffer.
                       ## i.e. t0 should eventually equal t2
    addi $t6 , $t6 , 1 ## One more character survived if exxecution gets here 
    j loop1

nonalphanumeric:
    

    addi $t0 , $t0 , 1  ## Increment only t0(and not t1)since we just want to skip the nonalphanumerics
                        ## i.e. do nothing else other than to go to the next memory address 
                        ## of the reading buffer , i.e. just skip the character and check the 
                        ## next one 
    j loop1             ## Continue back in loop until all characters are read .

exitloop1:

    ## To get here it means that we have read and processed all the characters from memory 
    ## So we revert the execution back to main 
    ## And since this routine did not contain any syscalls (i.e. we did not overwrite any
    ## register of the following :$a0,$a1,$a2,$a3,$v0,$v1) we did not need to do anything else 
    ## other than to return in $v0 the new number of characters in string(after the processing)
    ## and in $v1 the number of characters that were removed from the initial string

    add $v0 , $t6 , $zero ## pass our counter to v0 i.e. the number of character after processing
  ##  sub $v1 , $ , $t6   ## substract the counter from a2(=number of characters read) to get
                          ## the desired return value in v1 (as per the assignment's needs/instructions)
    
    jr $ra 

output_string:

    ## Save $a0 since there are syscalls in this routine 

      add $t0 , $a0 , $zero ## t0 = a0

      ##print the message "The string is:"   
      li $v0 , 4 
      la $a0 , out_string1 
      syscall

      
      ##print the characters in the processed buffer as a string
      li $v0 , 4
      la $a0 , buffer1
      syscall 
    
      add $a0 , $t0 , $zero ## Recover a0 
      
      jr $ra
```

I tried using an extra register in get_string ,initializing it to zero , then performing inside the loop0 an or operation with the character in t2 and a shift left logical by 8 bits but to no result

Edit :
Okay so far this is what I have come up with :

```
.data 
 ## Data declaration section

 ## The data declaration section is the same as that of the previous lab exercise 
 ## Two sets of 100 consecutive bytes are allocated and then the strings to be printed
 ## are declared 
    
 ## String to be printed
    out_string: .asciiz "\nPlease Enter your Character: \n"
    out_string1: .asciiz "\nThe string is:\n"

    buffer: .align 2
            .space 100   ## Allocate 100 consecutive bytes in memory
                         ## One character takes up 1 byte ,thus for 100 characters 
                         ## as per the assignment's needs, we need 100 bytes , this buffer
                         ## is for the reading of the user's input
                         ## This buffer is used for reading the user's input only

    buffer1: .align 2
             .space 100  ## Allocate another 100 consecutive bytes in memory
                         ## This buffer is used for filtering out the unwanted symbols
                         ## And contains the final string to be printed 


.text 
main:           ## Code execution starts here - MIPS - Assembly language instructions go 
                ## in text segment .  As per instructions 'main' does 4 jal(jump and links)
                ## code commands and executes exit 

    jal init                ## call the init() routine to initialize some parameters

    add $a0 , $s4 , $zero   ## pass the address of buffer(=string1 in assignment) into $a0
                            ## as an argument for the process_string routine 
                            ## (base address of buffer is in $s4)

    jal get_string          ## call the get_string(int string1, int num_characters) routine 
                            ## to read input from the user

    add $a1 , $s5 , $zero   ## pass the address of buffer1(=string2 in assignment) into $a1
                            ## as an argument for the process_string routine 
                            ## (base address of buffer1 is in $s5)

    add $a2 , $v0 , $zero   ## after the execution of get_string $v0 contains the number of 
                            ## characters that were read from the user. We store the current 
                            ## value of $v0 into register $a2 because the number of characters
                            ## that were read from the user is passed as an argument into 
                            ## the process_string routine

    jal process_string      ## call the process_string(int string1,int string2,int num_characters) 
                            ## routine to apply some filtering to the characters provided by the user
    
    add $a0 , $a1 , $v0   ## a0 is a memory address : the base address of buffer1(=string2) + 
                          ## the number of characters that exist in the post-processing  string 


    jal output_string       ## call the output_string(int string2) routine to print the processed string
    
    li $v0, 10              ## terminate the program
    syscall 

init:  

############ In this routine we populate the $s0,$s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5,$s6 registers that 
############ are preserved across calls of routines .

    li $s0 , 32             ## 32 = SP in ASCII 
    li $s1 , 57             ## 57 = 9  in ASCII 
    li $s2 , 64             ## 64 = @  in ASCII 
    li $s3 , 90             ## 90 = Z  in ASCII  
    la $s4 , buffer         ## load the base address of buffer(string1)  
    la $s5 , buffer1        ## load the base address of buffer1(string2) 
    li $s6 , 100            ## 100 times is the maximum amount of times the reading loop can run
    
    jr $ra                  ## continue execution back in main 


get_string:

############ In this routine we print the string : "Please enter your character" and proceed
############ to read input from the user for up to 100 characters. If the user enters @ we
############ stop reading and revert back to main where the processing of the input kicks off

    add $t9 , $a0 , $zero    ## First save the argument passed into the routine to a temporary
                             ## register $t9 in order to preserve it across syscalls  . 
                             ## The argument is the starting address of the 
                             ## reading buffer so now $t9 contains the base address of buffer
                             ## (the buffer used for reading = string1 in the assignment) 
                             ## $t9 is used to restore the value of $a0 later .

    add $t0 , $t9 , $zero    ## Copy the content of $t9 to $t0 to use it later in the loop0 

    li   $t1 , 0             ## Initialize a counter for the loop that follows
    
    li   $t8 , 1        ## Initialize another counter for the store word procedure

    add $t2 , $zero ,$zero 


loop0: ## The loop that prints the "Please enter your character" message and 
       ## gets input from the user
       ## We can safely overwrite $a0 register since we have transferred its value to 
       ## $t0 .
    
       ##print the message: "Please Enter your Character"
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, out_string
       syscall


       ## read a character from the user 
       li $v0, 12
       syscall

       

       beq $s2 , $v0 , exitloop0    ## Check if the character entered is @ (@ = 64 is in $s2)

       beq $t2 , $zero , firstchar

       beq $t8 , 4, lastCharOfWd    ## Check if the 4th byte is reached - a word has 4 bytes 
                                    ## If so jump to label "store" in which the actual storing
                                    ## of the words (and consequently bytes) take place.
       
       ##beq $v0 , $s6 , exitloop1    ## Check if the routine has already been called 100 times

       sll $t2 , $t2 , 8            ## Shift left logigal $t2 by 8bits = 1 byte 

       or $t2 , $t2 , $v0           ## Move the user's input to $t2 
       
       addi $t1 , $t1 , 1           ## Increment the counter of the loop 

       addi $t8 , $t8 , 1           ## Increment the counter for the bytes

       j loop0 

firstchar:

        add $t2 , $zero , $v0 

        addi $t1 , $t1 , 1           ## Increment the counter of the loop 

        addi $t8 , $t8 , 1           ## Increment the counter for the bytes 

        j loop0 

lastCharOfWd:

        sll $t2 , $t2 , 8            ## Shift left logigal $t2 by 8bits = 1 byte 

        or $t2 , $t2 , $v0           ## Move the user's input to $t2 
       
        
        sw $t2 , 0($t0)             ## Store the word in memory 

        li $t8 , 1     ## Reinitialize the counter for the bytes

        addi $t0 , $t0 , 4           ## Jump to the next word of the reading buffer

        add $t2 , $zero , $zero       ## Re-initialize t2                       

        j loop0                      ## Go back in loop 

exitloop0:

        sw $t2 , 0($t0)              ## Store any remaining characters

        add $a0 , $t9 , $zero        ## Restore $a0 

        add $v0 , $t1 , $zero        ## Pass the return value

        jr $ra                       ## Continue execution back in main 


exitloop1:


       add $a0 , $t9 , $zero        ## Restore $a0 

       add $v0 , $t1 , $zero        ## Pass the return value

       jr $ra                       ## Continue execution back in main 


process_string:


        add $t0 , $a0 , $zero       ## t-registers are not preserved across calls in mips and 
                                    ## thus can be overwritten

        add $t1 , $a2 , $zero       ## $t0 contains the base address of the reading buffer
                                    ## and $t1 the number of characters read from the user
        

        li $t2 , 0                 

        add $t3 , $a1 , $zero       ## $t3 contains the base address of the buffer
                                    ## used for the processed string 

        li $t9 , 1                 ## A counter to know when to store the word 

        add $t5 , $zero , $zero     ## Initialize the register that will contain a character
        add $t4 , $zero , $zero 
        li $v0 , 0

loopforWords:

############ Here , a loop for all the words in the buffer used for reading is performed.
############ Inside it , there is another loop that checks the bytes i.e. the characters
############ inside the word and filters out the non alphanumerical characters by simply 
############ jumping to the next byte of the word . If it is empty a new word is loaded from
############ memory . If all words are retrieved from memory execution jumps to the label :
############ exitloopforWords

        lw $t4 , 0($t0)                    ## load a word from memory location=t0+0 into t4 
        beq $t4 , $zero , exitloopforWords ## if there is no word any more go to exitloop1 label 

        

loopforBytes: 

        

        beq $t4 , $zero , getNewWord    ## If t4 is zero in here it means the end of the 
                                        ## word is reached . 
        andi $t5 , $t4 , 0x000000FF     ## To extract a character of the word a bit
                                        ## mask is used and a bit-wise AND is performed
        add $t6 , $zero , $zero 
        add $t8 , $zero , $zero 

        


        ## Case a

        slti $t6 , $t5 , 48     ## $t6 = 1 if $t5 < 48 else 0

        slt $t8 , $s0 , $t5     ## $t8 = 1 if $s0 < $t5 (32 < $t5) else 0

        and $t6 , $t6 , $t8     ## we want to find the numbers between 32 and 48 so both $t8 and
                                ## $t6 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                                ## in this region

        beq $t6 , 1 , nonalphanumeric       ## now if $t6 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                            ## a non alphanumeric
                                
    
        ## Case b

        slti $t6 , $t5 , 64     ## $t6 = 1 if $t5 < 64 else 0

        slt $t8 , $s1 , $t5     ## $t8 = 1 if $s0 < $t3 (57 < $t5) else 0

        and $t6 , $t6 , $t8     ## we want to find the numbers between 57 and 64 so both $t8 and
                                ## $t6 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                                ## in this region

        beq $t6 , 1 , nonalphanumeric       ## now if $t6 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                            ## a non alphanumeric
                                
        ## Case c

        slti $t6 , $t5 , 97     ## $t6 = 1 if $t5 < 97 else 0

        slt $t8 , $s3 , $t5     ## $t8 = 1 if $s3 < $t3 (90 < $t5) else 0

        and $t6 , $t6 , $t8     ## we want to find the numbers between 90 and 97 so both $t8 and
                                ## $t6 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                                ## in this region

        beq $t6 , 1 , nonalphanumeric       ## now if $t6 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                            ## a non alphanumeric
                                
        ## Case d 

        slti $t8 , $t5 , 122 ## $t8 = 1 if $t5 < 122 else 0 
        beq  $t8, $zero , nonalphanumeric

        ## By this stage all possibilities that $t5 contains a non-alphanumeric
        ## character are eliminated . If $t5 contained a non alphanumeric character execution 
        ## continues at label non alphanumeric 

       
        beq $t9 , 4 , storeTheWord ## If t9 = 4 time to store the word  

        sll $t7 , $t7 , 8 ## Shift t7 by 8bits=1byte

        or $t7 , $t7 , $t5 ## Get the character in t7 

        addi $t9 , $t9 , 1 ## Increment t9

        addi $t2 , $t2 ,1 ## Increment total character count 

        j getNewByte







getNewByte:

        srl $t4,$t4,8 ## shift right logical to the next byte (8bits) of the word 


        j loopforBytes

nonalphanumeric:

       j getNewByte


storeTheWord:

        sll $t7 , $t7 , 8 ## Shift one last time

        or $t7 , $t7 , $t5 ## Get the character in 

        sw $t7 , 0($t3) ## Store the word

        addi $t3 , $t3 , 4 ## Go to the next memory position of the buffer used for processing

        li $t9 , 1     ## Re - initialize the counter for the bytes

        add $t7 , $zero , $zero ## Re - initialize t7 for the next word

        addi $t2 , $t2 ,1 ## Increment total character count 

        j getNewByte

getNewWord:

        addi $t0 , $t0 , 4  ## The next word is at t0 + 4

        j loopforWords

exitloopforWords:

    ## If execution gets here that means processing of the words is done however there 
    ## may be leftover characters that must be stored i.e. the last word 
    ## is not complete , so we must handle that, and before we perform the sw command
    ## we must make sure we don't . Afterwards execution gets back in main
     
     

     sw $t7 , 0($t3) ## Store the last word
    
     jr $ra 



output_string:

    

      ##print the message "The string is:"   
      li $v0 , 4 
      la $a0 , out_string1 
      syscall

      
      ##print the characters in the processed buffer as a string
      li $v0 , 4
      la $a0 , buffer1
      syscall 
    
      add $a0 , $t0 , $zero ## Recover a0 
      
      jr $ra
```

It works almost as intended , the only problem is that when a user enters a non-alphanumeric character in either the first or the second byte of every word the output string is malformed . Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you sure that "the assignment requires me to implement it with store word and load word (i.e. pack the bytes first then store them as a word when reading and when processing the string load words from memory and then process them byte by byte"?  I would say that is an artificial and odd requirement, so maybe you're misreading it.

Comment: Yes . It specifies the use of sw/lw instead of lb/sb

Comment: So then you should probably just write two functions that emulate `lb` and `sb` and use those.

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused I just started learning MIPS and as far as I know a word is 4 bytes meaning 32 bits whilst a byte is 8 bits.The assignment specifies that no other function should be written instead it says that using a loop to pack the data is the right approach. I don’t know I am seriously stuck.

Comment: Well, _"or operation with the character in t2 and a shift left logical by 8 bits but to no result"_ is the right approach so maybe show what you did. Make sure you shift first, then `or`. I.e. you want `*p = (*p << 8) | c` and increment `p` after 4 characters.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how and when we store the word.Could you maybe suggest a draft solution?

Comment: @Jester I have edited my original post could you perhaps suggest any changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found it :

```
.data 
 ## Data declaration section

 ## The data declaration section is the same as that of the previous lab exercise 
 ## Two sets of 100 consecutive bytes are allocated and then the strings to be printed
 ## are declared 
    
 ## String to be printed
    out_string: .asciiz "\nPlease Enter your Character: \n"
    out_string1: .asciiz "\nThe string is:\n"

    buffer: .align 2
            .space 100   ## Allocate 100 consecutive bytes in memory
                         ## One character takes up 1 byte ,thus for 100 characters 
                         ## as per the assignment's needs, we need 100 bytes , this buffer
                         ## is for the reading of the user's input
                         ## This buffer is used for reading the user's input only

    buffer1: .align 2
             .space 100  ## Allocate another 100 consecutive bytes in memory
                         ## This buffer is used for filtering out the unwanted symbols
                         ## And contains the final string to be printed 


.text 
main:           ## Code execution starts here - MIPS - Assembly language instructions go 
                ## in text segment .  As per instructions 'main' does 4 jal(jump and links)
                ## code commands and executes exit 

    jal init                ## call the init() routine to initialize some parameters

    add $a0 , $s4 , $zero   ## pass the address of buffer(=string1 in assignment) into $a0
                            ## as an argument for the process_string routine 
                            ## (base address of buffer is in $s4)

    jal get_string          ## call the get_string(int string1, int num_characters) routine 
                            ## to read input from the user

    add $a1 , $s5 , $zero   ## pass the address of buffer1(=string2 in assignment) into $a1
                            ## as an argument for the process_string routine 
                            ## (base address of buffer1 is in $s5)

    add $a2 , $v0 , $zero   ## after the execution of get_string $v0 contains the number of 
                            ## characters that were read from the user. We store the current 
                            ## value of $v0 into register $a2 because the number of characters
                            ## that were read from the user is passed as an argument into 
                            ## the process_string routine

    jal process_string      ## call the process_string(int string1,int string2,int num_characters) 
                            ## routine to apply some filtering to the characters provided by the user
    
    add $a0 , $a1 , $v0   ## a0 is a memory address : the base address of buffer1(=string2) + 
                          ## the number of characters that exist in the post-processing  string 


    jal output_string       ## call the output_string(int string2) routine to print the processed string
    
    li $v0, 10              ## terminate the program
    syscall 

init:  

############ In this routine we populate the $s0,$s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5,$s6 registers that 
############ are preserved across calls of routines .

    li $s0 , 32             ## 32 = SP in ASCII 
    li $s1 , 57             ## 57 = 9  in ASCII 
    li $s2 , 64             ## 64 = @  in ASCII 
    li $s3 , 90             ## 90 = Z  in ASCII  
    la $s4 , buffer         ## load the base address of buffer(string1)  
    la $s5 , buffer1        ## load the base address of buffer1(string2) 
    li $s6 , 100            ## 100 times is the maximum amount of times the reading loop can run
    
    jr $ra                  ## continue execution back in main 


get_string:

############ In this routine we print the string : "Please enter your character" and proceed
############ to read input from the user for up to 100 characters. If the user enters @ we
############ stop reading and revert back to main where the processing of the input kicks off

    add $t9 , $a0 , $zero    ## First save the argument passed into the routine to a temporary
                             ## register $t9 in order to preserve it across syscalls  . 
                             ## The argument is the starting address of the 
                             ## reading buffer so now $t9 contains the base address of buffer
                             ## (the buffer used for reading = string1 in the assignment) 
                             ## $t9 is used to restore the value of $a0 later .

    add $t0 , $t9 , $zero    ## Copy the content of $t9 to $t0 to use it later in the loop0 

    li   $t1 , 0             ## Initialize a counter for the loop that follows
    
    li   $t8 , 1        ## Initialize another counter for the store word procedure

    add $t2 , $zero ,$zero 


loop0: ## The loop that prints the "Please enter your character" message and 
       ## gets input from the user
       ## We can safely overwrite $a0 register since we have transferred its value to 
       ## $t0 .
    
       ##print the message: "Please Enter your Character"
       li $v0, 4
       la $a0, out_string
       syscall


       ## read a character from the user 
       li $v0, 12
           syscall

       

       beq $s2 , $v0 , exitloop0    ## Check if the character entered is @ (@ = 64 is in $s2)

       beq $t2 , $zero , firstchar

       beq $t8 , 4, lastCharOfWd    ## Check if the 4th byte is reached - a word has 4 bytes 
                                    ## If so jump to label "store" in which the actual storing
                                    ## of the words (and consequently bytes) take place.
       
       ##beq $v0 , $s6 , exitloop1    ## Check if the routine has already been called 100 times

       sll $t2 , $t2 , 8            ## Shift left logigal $t2 by 8bits = 1 byte 

       or $t2 , $t2 , $v0           ## Move the user's input to $t2 
       
       addi $t1 , $t1 , 1           ## Increment the counter of the loop 

       addi $t8 , $t8 , 1           ## Increment the counter for the bytes

       j loop0 

firstchar:

        add $t2 , $zero , $v0 

        addi $t1 , $t1 , 1           ## Increment the counter of the loop 

        addi $t8 , $t8 , 1           ## Increment the counter for the bytes 

        j loop0 

lastCharOfWd:

        sll $t2 , $t2 , 8            ## Shift left logigal $t2 by 8bits = 1 byte 

        or $t2 , $t2 , $v0           ## Move the user's input to $t2 
       
        
        sw $t2 , 0($t0)             ## Store the word in memory 

        li $t8 , 1     ## Reinitialize the counter for the bytes

        addi $t0 , $t0 , 4           ## Jump to the next word of the reading buffer

        add $t2 , $zero , $zero       ## Re-initialize t2                       

        j loop0                      ## Go back in loop 

exitloop0:

        sw $t2 , 0($t0)              ## Store any remaining characters

        add $a0 , $t9 , $zero        ## Restore $a0 

        add $v0 , $t1 , $zero        ## Pass the return value

        jr $ra                       ## Continue execution back in main 


exitloop1:


       add $a0 , $t9 , $zero        ## Restore $a0 

       add $v0 , $t1 , $zero        ## Pass the return value

       jr $ra                       ## Continue execution back in main 


process_string:


        add $t0 , $a0 , $zero       ## t-registers are not preserved across calls in mips and 
                                    ## thus can be overwritten

        add $t1 , $a2 , $zero       ## $t0 contains the base address of the reading buffer
                                    ## and $t1 the number of characters read from the user
        

        li $t2 , 0                 

        add $t3 , $a1 , $zero       ## $t3 contains the base address of the buffer
                                    ## used for the processed string 

        li $t9 , 1                 ## A counter to know when to store the word 

        add $t5 , $zero , $zero     ## Initialize the register that will contain a character
        add $t4 , $zero , $zero 
        li $v0 , 0

loopforWords:

############ Here , a loop for all the words in the buffer used for reading is performed.
############ Inside it , there is another loop that checks the bytes i.e. the characters
############ inside the word and filters out the non alphanumerical characters by simply 
############ jumping to the next byte of the word . If it is empty a new word is loaded from
############ memory . If all words are retrieved from memory execution jumps to the label :
############ exitloopforWords

        lw $t4 , 0($t0)                    ## load a word from memory location=t0+0 into t4 
        beq $t4 , $zero , exitloopforWords ## if there is no word any more go to exitloop1 label 

        

loopforBytes: 

        

        beq $t4 , $zero , getNewWord    ## If t4 is zero in here it means the end of the 
                                        ## word is reached . 
        andi $t5 , $t4 , 0x000000FF     ## To extract a character of the word a bit
                                        ## mask is used and a bit-wise AND is performed
         

        


        ## Case a

        add $t6 , $zero , $zero 
        add $t8 , $zero , $zero

        slti $t6 , $t5 , 48     ## $t6 = 1 if $t5 < 48 else 0

        slt $t8 , $s0 , $t5     ## $t8 = 1 if $s0 < $t5 (32 < $t5) else 0

        and $t6 , $t6 , $t8     ## we want to find the numbers between 32 and 48 so both $t8 and
                                ## $t6 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                                ## in this region

        beq $t6 , 1 , nonalphanumeric       ## now if $t6 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                            ## a non alphanumeric
                                
    
        ## Case b

        add $t6 , $zero , $zero 
        add $t8 , $zero , $zero

        slti $t6 , $t5 , 64     ## $t6 = 1 if $t5 < 64 else 0

        slt $t8 , $s1 , $t5     ## $t8 = 1 if $s0 < $t3 (57 < $t5) else 0

        and $t6 , $t6 , $t8     ## we want to find the numbers between 57 and 64 so both $t8 and
                                ## $t6 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                                ## in this region

        beq $t6 , 1 , nonalphanumeric       ## now if $t6 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                            ## a non alphanumeric
                                
        ## Case c

        add $t6 , $zero , $zero 
        add $t8 , $zero , $zero

        slti $t6 , $t5 , 97     ## $t6 = 1 if $t5 < 97 else 0

        slt $t8 , $s3 , $t5     ## $t8 = 1 if $s3 < $t3 (90 < $t5) else 0

        and $t6 , $t6 , $t8     ## we want to find the numbers between 90 and 97 so both $t8 and
                                ## $t6 should be 1 when a character from the user has an ASCII code
                                ## in this region

        beq $t6 , 1 , nonalphanumeric       ## now if $t6 does indeed equal 1 we have 
                                            ## a non alphanumeric
                                
        ## Case d 

        add $t6 , $zero , $zero 
        add $t8 , $zero , $zero

        slti $t8 , $t5 , 122 ## $t8 = 1 if $t5 < 122 else 0 
        beq  $t8, $zero , nonalphanumeric

        ## By this stage all possibilities that $t5 contains a non-alphanumeric
        ## character are eliminated . If $t5 contained a non alphanumeric character execution 
        ## continues at label non alphanumeric 

       
        beq $t9 , 4 , storeTheWord ## If t9 = 4 time to store the word  

        sll $t7 , $t7 , 8 ## Shift t7 by 8bits=1byte

        or $t7 , $t7 , $t5 ## Get the character in t7 

        addi $t9 , $t9 , 1 ## Increment t9

        addi $t2 , $t2 ,1 ## Increment total character count 

        j getNewByte







getNewByte:

        srl $t4,$t4,8 ## shift right logical to the next byte (8bits) of the word 


        j loopforBytes

nonalphanumeric:

        srl $t4 , $t4 , 8

        beq $t4 , $zero , getNewWord

        j loopforBytes






storeTheWord:

        sll $t7 , $t7 , 8 ## Shift one last time

        or $t7 , $t7 , $t5 ## Get the character in 

        sw $t7 , 0($t3) ## Store the word

        addi $t3 , $t3 , 4 ## Go to the next memory position of the buffer used for processing

        li $t9 , 1     ## Re - initialize the counter for the bytes

        add $t7 , $zero , $zero ## Re - initialize t7 for the next word

        addi $t2 , $t2 ,1 ## Increment total character count 

        j getNewByte

getNewWord:

        addi $t0 , $t0 , 4  ## The next word is at t0 + 4

        j loopforWords

exitloopforWords:

    ## If execution gets here that means processing of the words is done however there 
    ## may be leftover characters that must be stored i.e. the last word 
    ## is not complete , so we must handle that, and before we perform the sw command
    ## we must make sure we don't . Afterwards execution gets back in main
     
     

     sw $t7 , 0($t3) ## Store the last word
    
     jr $ra 



output_string:

    

      ##print the message "The string is:"   
      li $v0 , 4 
      la $a0 , out_string1 
      syscall

      
      ##print the characters in the processed buffer as a string
      li $v0 , 4
      la $a0 , buffer1
      syscall 
    
      add $a0 , $t0 , $zero ## Recover a0 
      
      jr $ra
```

What do you think ?

Comment: It does seem to have the correct pieces and if it works, I'll say it's fine :D

Comment: Yeah it works but I just saw that for input Hello$World@ it returns for some reason HelldoWorl . Similar to the problem in the edit . but now the problem arises only when there is a next word in the reading buffer can I work around it ?Thanks for your time and input in advance.Otherwise it works as expected.

Comment: @Jester The way I understand it this must be due to the way and order the input is stored with sw .